# Software RAID missing after replacing motherboard - how to restore?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I had a perfectly good software raid (md0) on my Linux Mint 19 installation.  I replaced the motherboard, using the exact same drives as before.  However, now the RAID doesn't exist and won't assemble.

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md0: No such file or directory


# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>


# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)


# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

The drives appear to be fine, hardware-wise (sdc and sdd), but fdisk shows that sdd has no partitions?

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8735B481-9712-4066-A16C-ABA9C9E23422

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdd: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 948195E0-E97D-4693-8698-E808146423FA
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to have been a software RAID on these drives. You might find more information about what is really going on by using the `blkid` command.

Comment: There very definitely was - I still even have the mdadm.conf entry:  ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=e6645285:e7ab9816:b8139108:5e171016 name=tir-na-nog:0

Comment: FWIW, here's blkid: /dev/sdc1: LABEL="4TB_HGST02" UUID="20fabea8-7514-449f-adf1-bf4ddab217f7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bdb79e48-4d5d-477a-9665-5186f002573d".  No entry for sdd, as for whatever reason it's not being seen as having a partition.

Comment: Why do you believe there was a software RAID on these two drives? Have you looked at the other two drives? Why not?

Comment: Because I'd been using those two drives as a RAID device for nearly year before changing up the mobo.  The other two drives are definitely not the RAID devices, as one is an SSD for system files and the other is a Windows install.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what happened, but I can only tell you that now there is no RAID on either of those disks, nor any evidence that there ever was.

Comment: Well, I don't know what happened either - hence my asking for help here.  There is certainly evidence that there was, however - the mdadm.conf entry.

Comment: All that means is that your installed OS had a software RAID attached at some point. It doesn't indicate that it had anything to do with these specific disks.

Comment: Why would I lie about it???  There are only four disks in the machine, the mobo changed, and now two of those disks are performing exactly as before and the two that made up the raid are not.  It's not exactly rocket science.